# java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to store a Spark RDD to HBase

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, hdfs

I'm trying to load some data from HDFS into HBase as follows:

```
String dir = "/tmp/eloued";
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set(SequenceFileInputFormat.INPUT_DIR, dir);
// serialization
config.setStrings("io.serializations", config.get("io.serializations"),
        MutationSerialization.class.getName(),
        ResultSerialization.class.getName());
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> input = context.newAPIHadoopRDD(config, SequenceFileInputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Put.class);
JobConf jobConfig = new JobConf(config, this.getClass());
jobConfig.setOutputFormat(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat.class);
jobConfig.set(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName);
input.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConfig);
```

Inside the `dir` directory I have two folders as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop hadoop          0 2017-05-26 06:40 /tmp/eloued/object
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoop hadoop          0 2017-05-26 06:40 /tmp/eloued/object/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoop hadoop        896 2017-05-26 06:40 /tmp/eloued/object/part-r-00000
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop hadoop          0 2017-05-26 06:40 /tmp/eloued/status
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoop hadoop          0 2017-05-26 06:40 /tmp/eloued/status/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoop hadoop        111 2017-05-26 06:40 /tmp/eloued/status/part-r-00000
```

Now when I call the code above I see the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://tmp/eloued/object/data
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1914)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1124)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(JavaPairRDD.scala:836)
    at com.ddn.cloud.replication.storage.SparkConsumerJob.run(SparkConsumerJob.java:46)
    at dz.lab.HBaseSparkTest.testConsumerProcessObject(NSReplicationHBaseSparkTest.java:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Why the suffix `data` is added to the path spark will try to read data from? The strange thing is when the `dir` folder have only one subfolder then no exception is raised and the data is effectively stored in HBase.

Comment: Define `String dir = "/tmp/eloued";` as `String dir = "tmp/eloued";` i.e. remove leading /. this should solve I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to specify the different folders and separate them with `,`. So instead of:

```
config.set(SequenceFileInputFormat.INPUT_DIR, "/tmp/eloued");
```

I should have done:

```
config.set(SequenceFileInputFormat.INPUT_DIR, "/tmp/eloued/object,/tmp/eloued/status");
```

And it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change `/tmp/eloud` to `/tmp/eloued` and...you're done :)

Comment: no there is a typo (cause I changed the paths as they were too long), I will fix it.